# XCODE Obj-C add UiimageView programatically in a for

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

So i need to add programatically 3 images using a for loop this is my code , it's not correct, i just tryed.

```
for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++){
        UIImageView *[i] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([i]*50, 50, 250, 250)];

[self.view addSubview:[i]];
    }
```

where [i]; will be 1 , 2 and 3 any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This code is creating 3 UIImageViews at same position. That's why you can't see all three in the view.

Comment: Your syntax for construction is ... horrible. You need to use a variable name where you have typed `[i]`. As in: `UIImageView *imageView = ... addSubview:imageView];`.

Comment: You're using the same variable for two different things _in one statement_. What the heck do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You syntax is wrong. This is more what you need.

```
for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
  UIImageView *image=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*50, 50, 250, 250)];
  [self.view addSubView:image];
}
```

However, this is not much use to you as your images are not referenced from anywhere so you can not populate or adjust them easily.

Comment: All views will have the same frame

Comment: Correct, but that is not what the question was so why the -1? The code example in the question is clearly useless. However the question was that the code does not work. Who knows what the plan for the images are once they have been added.

Comment: `CGRectMake([i]*50, 50, 250, 250)` <- we know that OP wants to change the frame for each image.

Answer (score 0):

Change the variable name from `[i]` to some name like `imageToAdd`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGFloat xMarging = 0;
CGFloat imageOriginX = 0;
CGFloat imageOriginY = 0;
CGFloat imageWidth = 250;
CGFloat imageHeight = 250;
NSInteger numerOfImages = 3;
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < numerOfImages; i++){
    [self.view addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xMarging + i * imageWidth,
                                                                        imageOriginY,
                                                                        imageWidth,
                                                                        imgageHeight)]];
}
```

assuming you want them side by side as in [][][]